# Error "attribute parameter is not in hash ref" when using Perl DBI selectall_hashref

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm trying to get my first select to work using `selectall_hashref` from the Perl DBI module.   I've opened a connection to the database (MySQL) successfully.   I'm getting an error when I execute the following:

```
$dbh->selectall_hashref('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?',undef,"myusername");
```

> DBI::st=HASH(0x1505a60)->_prepare(...): attribute parameter 'myusername' is not a hash ref at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/DBD/mysql.pm line 238.

My table should be able to support this query, it has an `id` column and `login` column for each user.

The examples I've found for `selectall_hashref` show the `?` substitution parameter being passed as the third parameter.   The [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.634/DBI.pm#selectrow_hashref) says that the second and third arguments should be `%attr` and `@bind_values` but doesn't give much documentation about them or show working examples.

What is causing the error, and more importantly how do you actually use the `%attr` and `@bind_values` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store everything as an arrayref where each row is a hashref (which is what your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380509/error-attribute-parameter-is-not-in-hash-ref-when-using-perl-dbi-selectall-has#comment58465917_35380583) seems to indicate), you can use the `selectall_arrayref()` method with the `Slice` attribute:

```
$dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?', {Slice => {}}, 'myusername');
```

It's a little weird, but [here's how it works](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref):

> If $slice is a hash reference, `fetchall_arrayref` fetches each row as
>   a hash reference. If the $slice hash is empty then the keys in the
>   hashes have whatever name lettercase is returned by default. (See
>   "[FetchHashKeyName](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#FetchHashKeyName)" attribute.) If the $slice hash is *not* empty,
>   then it is used as a slice to select individual columns by name. The
>   values of the hash should be set to 1. The key names of the returned
>   hashes match the letter case of the names in the parameter hash,
>   regardless of the "[FetchHashKeyName](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#FetchHashKeyName)" attribute.

It's a good idea to set the `FetchHashKeyName` attribute on the database handle to make your hash key names consistent; I happen to like `NAME_lc` in my applications.

Answer (score 2):

The methods expects key column as the second parameter and attributes ref is passed as third one. In the result it builds a hash with the specified column as a key. What you probably want, is `selectall_arrayref`:

```
$ dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?',undef,"myusername");
```

Comment: I was hoping to get back a hashref like `{"id"->1}` which is why I chose the hashref version.   Does the hashref refer to the parameters it takes rather than what it returns?

Comment: I see. I'm afraid you need to go row by row and use fetchrow_hashref for this. DBI is slightly inconsistent regarding naming...

Comment: That's it.   I wanted `selectrow_hashref` not `selectall_hashref`.    I'd seen examples for both and copied the wrong code.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You _can_ use `selectall_arrayref()` to get everything as an arrayref of hashrefs.

Comment: The naming scheme is `selectX_Yref` where `X` is either `row`, `col` or `all`, and `Y` is either `array` or `hash`. The array or hash refers to the _outermost_ reference, i.e. the reference returned from the method, the container for the rows. The attribute parameter controls what's _inside_ the outermost reference.